# Generate truly random numbers with C++ (Windows 10 x64)

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to create a password generator. I used the `random` library, and after reading the documentation, I found out that `rand()` depends on an algorithm and a seed (`srand()`) to generate the random number. I tried using the current time as a seed (`srand(time(0))`), but that is not truly random. Is there a way to generate truly random numbers? Or maybe get the current time very accurately (like, in microseconds)? My platform is Windows 10 x64.

Comment: See https://qrng.anu.edu.au/ although will be orders of magnitude slower than the approaches available to you via the C++ standard library.

Comment: You're probably best off using your os's cryptographic random number generator apis or use a library like openssl or crypto++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that PCs cannot generate truly random numbers without dedicated hardware, however remember that each PC has at least one hardware random generator attached to it - that device is you, the user sitting in front of the computer. Human is a very random thing. Each one has its own speed of key presses, mouse movement patterns etc. This can be leveraged to your advantage.

On Linux you have a special device, `/dev/random` which uses exactly this. While you work on the PC, it collects random data (not security sensitive of course), such as how fast you tap the keyboard, and in addition hardware related data, such as intervals between interrupts, and some disk IO info. This all generates entropy, which is later used to generate pseudo random data, which is still not 100% random, but is based on much stronger random seed.

I am not an expert on Windows, but a quick search shows that Windows provides `CryptGenRandom` API, with somewhat similar functionality.

If you want to generate cryptographically strong random data, I suggest you start from this. Remember, this is still not as strong as dedicated hardware random generator. But this is good enough for most real world use cases.

Comment: CryptGenRandom is deprecated. MS says to use BCryptGenRandom from now on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom

Answer (score 3):

No, these are not truly random numbers. True randomness requires hardware support. Typically they work by sampling an analoge generated white noise signal.

Probably you want to seed your random generator with an always different value. A time() call would do it, or you can also hash it by the current pid ( getpid() ).

Comment: What is a pid? Does it require any libraries to find it?

Comment: Note that this "always different seed" is meant to be used once per run of your application, not once per random number retrieved.

Comment: The process id of the process. It is an integer. There is a column for them in the Details view of the task manager.

Comment: @DevSolar why not using it every time I create new random number?

Comment: @xDev120: A good PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) will, *once seeded*, and over a series of continuous calls to its generating function, generate a sequence of numbers that lacks non-random  characteristics, and thus make predictions impossible (unless you know the exact algorithm). However, if you keep re-seeding the algorithm each time, the algorithm will begin anew each time. Using time() for such re-seeding is a common mistake, and can allow an attacker to guess the algorithm used and thus a likely next number. You are basically defeating the purpose of the PRNG.

Comment: (ctd.) The quality if your PRNG degrades to the quality of your seed source, and time() is as non-random as it gets.

Comment: @AlanBirtles All of them are pseudorandom. The only way to have really random numbers, if you read them out from the physical world. Purely software solutions can only approximate it (imho far enough well and the true randomness is in most cases only security paranoia). Btw, there are security holes based on random generator prediction.

Comment: @peterh oops, sorry that was meant to be a comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rand()` to generate a password as per your question then I suggest you use some kind of cryptographic method as they will be much stronger and collision-resistant than the numbers generated by `rand()`. Use something like Openssl or something similar to that kind.

If not, then truly random numbers as suggested by 'peterh' need hardware support. Yet you can use much better functions than `rand()` such as [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). It is a better generator than rand() as rand just uses a simple [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Read about mt_19937 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine)